# How to allow one zone of eureka services to talk to multiple zones, while services in another zone is only allowed to talk with eachother

Tags: netflix-eureka

I have been trying to configure my eureka clients/servers to have this behavior, but cant make it work.

services in zone0 will only talk to each other and never with zone1 or zone2

services in zone1 will prefer to talk to each other but can also talk to zone0 if a service is not avaliable but never with zone2

services in zone2 will prefer to talk to each other but can also talk to zone0 if a service is not avaliable but never with zone1

I would expect the following client configurations to work, i dont know if im missing something or if i just have misunderstood the hole thing :)

clients in zone0

```
eureka.instance.metadataMap.zone=zone0
eureka.client.zone0.availabilityZones=zone0
eureka.client.serviceUrl.zone0=http://zone0.localdomain/eureka
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://zone0.localdomain/eureka
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.preferSameZone=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```

clients in zone1

```
eureka.instance.metadataMap.zone=zone1
eureka.client.zone1.availabilityZones=zone1,zone0
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://zone1.localdomain/eureka
eureka.client.serviceUrl.zone1=http://zone1.localdomain/eureka
eureka.client.serviceUrl.zone0=http://zone0.localdomain/eureka
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.preferSameZone=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```

clients in zone2

```
eureka.instance.metadataMap.zone=zone2
eureka.client.zone2.availabilityZones=zone2,zone0
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://zone2.localdomain/eureka
eureka.client.serviceUrl.zone2=http://zone2.localdomain/eureka
eureka.client.serviceUrl.zone0=http://zone0.localdomain/eureka
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.preferSameZone=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
```